# Hibernate 3 - MappingException - AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="xxxxclass"/>

Tags: java, hibernate, configuration, annotations, configuration-files

I tried my hand at writing a simple Hibernate 3 java program - to fetch data from DB, it works just fine when i try to configure with an `hbm.xml` file but when i use a model class to configure the same, I face issues as below. 
ie

```
<mapping class="example.Pojo_Stock"/>
```

instead of

```
<mapping resource="Pojo_Stock.hbm.xml" />
```

Although tried all related queries on stackoverflow (many marked as duplicate) but unable to find a solution. Kindly help

```
public class MainApp {

    private static SessionFactory factory; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            System.out.println("In Main method of MainApp...");

            Configuration configure=new Configuration();  
            configure.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            factory = configure.buildSessionFactory();

            MainApp mainApp = new MainApp();
            mainApp.listDetails_Stock();
        }
        catch(Throwable ex){

            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 

        }
    }

    public void listDetails_Stock(){
        System.out.println("In listDetails_Stock method of MainApp...");

        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try{
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            List<Pojo_Stock> details = session.createQuery("FROM Pojo_Stock").list();
            for(Pojo_Stock detail : details){
                System.out.print("\nStockId: " + detail.getStockId());
                System.out.print("\nStockCode: " + detail.getStockCode());
                System.out.print("\nStockName: " + detail.getStockName());
            }
            tx.commit();
        }


        catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }finally {
            session.close(); 
        }
    }
```

the model class looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STOCK")
public class Pojo_Stock {

    int StockId;    
    String StockCode;
    String StockName; 
    // Getters & Setters    
}
```

and my hibernate config looks like below,

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxx
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        xxxx
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
        xxxx
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
    <!--  <mapping resource="Pojo_Stock.hbm.xml" /> -->
    <mapping class="example.Pojo_Stock"/> 
</session-factory>
```

the error i get on my console is as below,

```
Failed to create sessionFactory object.org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="example.Pojo_Stock"/>
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at example.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:28)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="example.Pojo_Stock"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1479)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1458)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1432)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1352)
    at tutorialspoint.example.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:19)
```

I tried to use `AnnotationConfiguration()` instead of `Configuration()` that does not work instead throws the below error,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:262)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:69)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:540)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:451)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$300(URLClassLoader.java:79)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$ClassFinder.run(URLClassLoader.java:1038)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:314)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:429)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:665)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:644)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:358)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:627)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:85)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:162)
    at postgres.hibernate.lessons.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:28)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a issue with your `.jar` files. You are not using latest `.jars`. You are trying a annotational Configuration in your `pojo`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STOCK")
public class Pojo_Stock {

    int StockId;    
    String StockCode;
    String StockName; 
    // Getters & Setters    
}
```

So, First Please use  `AnnotationConfiguration()` instead of `Configuration()`;
but you have tried already this.

So, I think (possibly) you are using **incompatible versions of hibernate core and annotations**. One of the possible combination is **Hibernate Core 3.3.2 with Hibernate Annotations 3.4** and try. Have a look at the **Compatibility matrix** [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-to-use/) for more details.

or

You may also Try this link [Hibernate-Error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-error-an-annotationconfiguration-instance-is-required-to-use/)